# I am working on windows phone 8.1 application and want to know that is it possible to get sim number programatically in wp 8.1 app?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I want to retrive sim number from wp 8.1 application . is it possible with current SDk? or is it possible in windows 10 SDK?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible or not but maybe not since all the applications such as what's app or truecaller let the user input the number by himself.

and I think it would be much easier to use the same trick if it fits your application.

Comment: I confirm. You can't have the sim number in 8.1. An input text is the way to go.